# plotting the wanted ranges in xyscatter graph with VBA

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I am trying to create a xy plot where the x values is the time axis (column A) and the y values are in the other columns. (in the example only C and D)
When I try my code from below, I get a graph with time axis (so column A) and y values all the other columns (B, C, D, E,...) which is unwanted.

I can see that the .seriescollection(1) and (2) overwrite the default y-values (because my range is smaller), but all the others (column B, D, E,...) still remains in the graph.

Any thoughts why? Thanks in advance!

```
    Sub grafieken()
'
' grafieken Macro
'
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim naaaam As String

naaam = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(naaam)
Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrt
    'Data?
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = sh.Range("$C$1")
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range("$A$2:$A$11")
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = sh.Range("$C$2:$C$11")
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = sh.Range("$D$1")
    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = sh.Range("$A$2:$A$11")
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = sh.Range("$D$2:$D$11")

    'Titles?
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = naaam

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what range do you have selected when you run the code to get the chart? if the active cell is within the chart data range, it will automatically populate the whole range when you add the chart. Try placing this line after `Set sh = ..` - `sh.Range("A15").Select`

Comment: hello Scott, when I try this, i get a blank chart.

Comment: this worked for me as is with the exception of having to add a `.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` before adding the 2nd series. Perhaps try changing the `sh.Range("C1")` line to "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.Range("$C$1").Address` and follow suit for the other `Name, XValues, and Values` calls.

Comment: Does it also work for you when you have data from A1:F50? Because it allways shows everything and only for the 2 series it is changed to 10 datapoints insted of 50...

Answer (score 0):

```
  Sub grafieken()

Dim MySh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim naaaam As String

naaam = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

Set MySh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(naaam)
Set chrt = MySh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

 With chrt
'Data?
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(naaam).Range("A1:B11")
.ChartType = xlXYScatter
.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E11")
'.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1")
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$A$11")
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2:$C$11")

'Titles?
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = naaam

End With

End Sub
```

I found a way, I first needed to define the source data for the first series, and change them later into the one I want, this way no unwanted series appears.